# Que signifie « un par binôme » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire

Il est souvent demandé de faire des travaux en binôme et de rédiger un texte, une présentation.
Ma question est peut-être bête (que signifie « un par binôme » ?) mais elle porte sur une ambiguïté dans le contexte de mon travail.

Nous devons réaliser une présentation d'une vidéo et rendre un petit dossier écrit.
Ce travail se fait par binôme.
Une fiche nous a été donnée afin de savoir quel est le contenu du dossier.
À la fin, dans conclusion, il y a marqué :

> Apprentissage (1 par binôme)

Et c'est cela que nous ne comprenons pas; pourquoi ici est-il stipulé « 1 par binôme ? » pour nous ce groupe de mots signifie « un pour deux », soit un apprentissage pour 2.
Mais alors pourquoi le préciser ?

J'aimerais donc savoir si « 1 par binôme » signifie bien « 1 pour 2 ? »

Comment: Que signifie « apprentissage » dans ce contexte ?

Comment: Cela signifie se que nous avons appris de la vidéo, quels sont les choses qui sont biens à prendre en compte et que pouvons nous prendre pour exemple pour améliorer notre communication (C'est une vidéo de communication.)

Comment: "1 par binôme" signifie bien "un pour deux". Enfin il y a une ambigüité avec "1 pour 2", les deux élèves pourraient être de binômes différents. C'est plus exact de dire que ça signifie "un par groupe".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il me semble que le terme « apprentissage » ne corresponde pas à ce qui est demandé et qu'il s'agisse plutôt de **l'enseignement** qui est à tirer de la vidéo. «  1 par binôme » ne signifie pas autre chose que « 1 pour 2 »  et je crois qu'il faut tout simplement considérer que cela est répété pour insister que aussi dans cette partie du travail demandé il est question d'un seul compte-rendu rédigé en commun.

ADDITION

Il peut y avoir une erreur ci-dessus; ce qui semble évident pourrait ne pas être   correct; voilà la définition de « binôme » dans le contexte du travail à deux,  mais c'est de l'argot :

> (TLfi) « Lorsque deux camarades travaillent régulièrement l'un près de l'autre, comme il est d'usage à l'École, chacun d'eux est dit le binôme de l'autre ».

**Dans ce cas il est nécessaire que chacun des deux coéquipiers produise son propre compte-rendu.**

D'après le Larousse la définition de « binôme » comprend 2 possibilités :

> Familier. 
>   Ensemble constitué de deux éléments, de deux personnes considérés en 
>   bloc
>
> Argot.
>   scolaire. Camarade de travail, de chambre.

Il faut s'assurer auprès des préparateurs des fiches qu'ils utilisent bien le même terme du début jusqu'à la fin.

Comment: Dans le contexte d'intitulé de devoirs, ***un par binôme*** s'oppose à ***un par élève*** et signifie donc toujours ***un par groupe de deux personnes***.